# Using UICollectionView In iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array with 10 entries. I want to display them on UICollectionView as 3 in each row so they will be like

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
J
```

Now I am using following code

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [self.btnArray count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Buttons *btn = [self.btnArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section * indexPath.row)];
    NSURL* aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:btn.imagePath];
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aURL];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

// 1
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize retval =  CGSizeMake(75, 75);
    return retval;
}

// 3
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20);
}
```

However When I hit

```
 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

It gives me error

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Sounds to me like it's telling you how to fix it.  Did you do one of those things?

Comment: @CarlNorum http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12 I am using pre made layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, you need to register a nib or class for cells with that identifier.  You do this once when you setup your view.

See the UICollectionView Documentation for these two methods:

```
– registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
– registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
```

Comment: You will call one of these methods in your viewDidLoad method.  If your cell uses an .xib file then use the registerNib method.  If it does not then use the registerClass method.  Read the documentation and it will explain more. Documentation is really helpful anytime questions like this arise.